# Автодополнение по нажатии tab

Tags: linux, c, shell

Доброго времени суток. Пишу командный интерпретатор.
Как я могу реализовать автодополнение по нажатии кнопки TAB? 
Т.е., предположим, я набираю t, нажимаю на TAB и команда преобразуется в touch.
Пишу на C.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline // а зачем создавать новую учётную запись, при [наличии существующей](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229232)?

Answer (score 1):

1. У Вас должен быть список всех слов, подлежащих автодополнению
2. Ввод команды пользователя должен производится не построчно, а посимвольно и без эха. Если введённый символ НЕ '\t' - выводите его эхо.
3. Если очередной введённый символ == '\t', то просматриваете свой список слов на предмет совпадения уже введённой части команды с началом всех хранимых слов.
4. Если сопадение ровно одно - выполняете автодополнение.
5. Если совпадений несколько - ждёте повторного ввода '\t' и далее - по известному алгоритму.

Comment: А можно сразу использовать [GNU Readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html) (можно вместе с [GNU History](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html))

Comment: Лично я не пользовался, поэтому однозначно сказать не могу. Посмотрел описание... Там есть такая вещь, как "Key Bindings". Т.е. можно на некоторые нажатия навесить строчку, которая будет подставляться. Но как сделать, что бы при нажатии \t подставлялись РАЗНЫЕ тексты, в зависимости от контекста - я не понял.

Comment: Ну, `\t` в этом случае все равно самому надо будет обрабатывать. Вот [тут](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_2.html) достаточно много примеров программирования (в т.ч. completions)  с этой либой.

Comment: Да, довольно интересно!